# ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Tags: python

Been getting this error after installing Python a  year or so. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jeriel\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\jeriel\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three options.
One is to just reinstall pip (`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`)

Another is to forever say `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip`.

If that stuff doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall Python. This is not the easiest, but it should fix the problem and you also get the latest version of Python if you so desire.